# How to change the background color or a Table cell depending on other column value in Jquery Datatable?

Tags: jquery

How to change the background color or a Table cell depending on other column value in Jquery Datatable ??

In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5fbo72rm/4/

The table has got three coulmns **Name ,Price and Quantity** .

How can i change the background color of that  Name cell if the quantity is greater than 40000

```
<table id="allwl">
    <th class="hidden-480">Price</th>
    <th class="hidden-480">Volume</th>
    <th class="hidden-480">Quantity</th>
</table>

var dataSet = [
    [
        "1441.75",
        "100"],
    [
        "1614.45",
        "50"

    ],
    [
        "834.15",
        "3000"]

];

var array_names = ["APPLE", "WHIRLPOOL", "SAMSUNG"];

for (var key in dataSet) {
    if (dataSet.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        dataSet[key].splice(0, 0, array_names[key]);
    }
}

$(function () {
    $('#allwl').dataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": -1,
            "data": dataSet,
            "columns": [{
            "title": "Name"
        }, {
            "title": "Price"
        }, {
            "title": "Quantity"
        }]
    });
})
```

I have tried with createdcell , but that is only working with that particuarlar cell ,not for other cell

Could anybody please help me ,how to resolve this ??

http://jsfiddle.net/5fbo72rm/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#allwl tr').each(function() {
    var abc = $(this).children('td').eq(2).html();
    if(!abc) {
    return false;
    }
    else {
        if(abc > 40000) {
            $(this).children('td').eq(0).css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    }
});
});
```

here is your jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sjkurani/5fbo72rm/9/